# How can I fetch RedisJSON and RedisTimeSeries values using Lettuce

Tags: redis, lettuce

I have an existing codebase that uses Jedis to enumerate and fetch diverse values from Redis: strings, hash, set, list, etc. as well as RedisJSON and RedisTimeSeries.

I am considering the replacement of Jedis with Lettuce as both the design and documentation seem more complete.

However, I cannot yet find a means of fetching module defined types, specifically [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) and [RedisTimesSeries](https://redis.io/docs/stack/timeseries/). I would be grateful for an example demonstrating how that's done.